# Price Sets for different groups

Tags: extension, price-sets

I've installed the group based pricing extension and enabled it, however I can't seem to get it to kick in. The two extra fields that are supposed to show don't appear. I'm using 4.7.7 and Drupal. Has anyone managed to get this extension to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this extension:
https://github.com/zengenuity/civicrm_groupprice/blob/master/info.xml

It's info.xml says it's compatible w/ 4.4 - I think that explains why you're having difficulty to get it to work on a 4.7.x

If this functionality is very important to you - the general guideline is:

1. contact the author of the extension
2. check with them on possible plans for an upgrade of the extension to a newer civicrm version
3. and what kind of funding it may take to get it there

Comment: Thanks Karin, i assumed as a newbie to Civi that it might work. Although enabled its doing nothing so my dilemma remains. I have a large lot of branches and each branch needs certain extra price sets over and above of the one price set we all use and I was hoping that each group would have a separate price set and other groups would not be able to see those price sets that didn't relate to them.

Comment: It's good to try - some extensions do work well on officially not supported versions - however not in this case

Comment: Let me amend my answer a bit

Comment: Awesome extension, too bad its not compatible with the latest version.